# How to auto refresh jComboBox data after update?

Tags: java, mysql, jcombobox

I have a `jComboBox` that getting data from MySQL server database.

When I add new data to database, the `jComboBox` doesn't show it, and I must reopen my program to add the new data to `jComboBox`.

How can I refresh `jComboBox` data automatically?

This is my code :

```
private void dataComboBox(){
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop","root","");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select id from perfume order by id asc";      
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);                             
        while(res.next()){
            Object[] ob = new Object[3];
            ob[0] = res.getString(1);
            jComboBox5.addItem(ob[0]);                                     
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}


private void showCBdata(){
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shop","root","");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "select name from perfume where id='"+jComboBox5.getSelectedItem()+"'";  
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);

    while(res.next()){
        Object[] ob = new Object[3];
        ob[0]=  res.getString(1);            
        jTextField8.setText((String) ob[0]);
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}


//call method
private void jComboBox5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    showCBdata();
}
```

can you help me?

thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in this way it will automatically refresh the `combobox`

```
try {
            comboBox.removeAllItems();

            sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
            rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String val = rs.getString("column_name");
            comboBox.addItem(val);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DefineCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

`removeAllItems();` method will clean the combobox to insure that not to repeat values.
You do not need to create a separate `Object` to add in `jComboBox` instead you can add `String` too.

Answer (score 1):

Inzimam Tariq IT's Code (above):

```
try {
            comboBox.removeAllItems();

            sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name`";
            rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String val = rs.getString("column_name");
            comboBox.addItem(val);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DefineCustomer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

I suggest putting all of this code inside an `ActionListener`. So that each time there the mouse is entered over the `comboBox` the above code will run. You should do the following:

```
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
       //the above code goes here
    }
```

I suggest using a `mouseListener`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

But if you want to look at other `ActionListeners` you can see them here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Answer (score 0):

Once you add a new registry in the DB, do a removeAllItems comboBox.removeAllItems(); and repopulate de combobox, 
My example:

```
jComboLicorerias.removeAllItems();

try {
        Conector = Conecta.getConexion();
        Statement St = Conector.createStatement();
        try (ResultSet Rs = St.executeQuery(Query)) {
            while (Rs.next()) {
                jComboLicorerias.addItem(Rs.getString("nombreLicoreria"));
            }
            St.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la consulta.");
```